# Blackberry: Getting uncaught exception java.lang.securityexception

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Here is my code to **open an image file** from `SDcard` in `Blackberry`

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DisplayAnImage extends MIDlet
{
    private Display mDisplay;
    private Form mForm;
    private Image pngBackground;
    public void startApp()
    {
        try{
            pngBackground = Image.createImage("file:///Media Card/test_image.png");
            ImageItem img = new ImageItem("bg",pngBackground,
            ImageItem.LAYOUT_EXPAND,"background",ImageItem.PLAIN);
            mForm = new Form("MIDlet Developer Guide: Display an image."); 
            mForm.append(img);
            mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
            mDisplay.setCurrent(mForm); 
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            mForm.append(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void pauseApp(){}

    public void destroyApp(boolean flag){}
}
```

While I am running this app with giving all permission to app it shows me `uncaught exception java.lang.securityexception`. Please somebody help me on this.

Thanks in advance.. :-)

Comment: Can you try catching `SecurityException` in another catch clause and printing the message you get in `e.getMessage()`?

Comment: try to debug. Show the exact line that will throw this error.

Comment: There is no such folder named `file:///Media Card/` on BlackBerry, you need to correct your path.